# create android phonegap push notification for phonegap 2.x

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I have a phonegap project on phonegap 2.9 and I need to add a push notification for android project ... all the tutorials  i have seen was  for phonegap 3 ... how to create push notification on phonegap 2.9

Comment: Try this [Push Notification](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/)

Comment: it's already obsolete..

Answer (score 0):

You can take an old version of the push plugin for phonegap:
https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

take a version from before the commit with the changes to 3.0.

if you wish, you can use the files from my own project's files (before i upgraded to 3.0, i saved a copy of my project's source files just to be safe in dropbox):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ewb0l8w3f8upj5b/PushNotification.js
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0xau2qccjpaatbv/weXMfDlpGZ

if you'll replace the current 3.0 version files with those it should work.